# Difference in results between anova and Anova (car)

Tags: r, anova, p-value, type-i-and-ii-errors, car

I have a question about using the anova function and Anova from the car package. I know there is a question about Type 1, 2 and 3, but the question is this: I am doing an analysis where I want to compare the average interactions in networks of floral visitors in three treatments (three categories). I am using three covariates to control for residuals. I have 17 networks (sampling unit) in two categories and 15 in one of the categories. However, when I use the anova function, the treatment is significant but when I use car's Anova, it does not. I am in doubt to understand the difference and evaluate which is the most correct to use.

I really appreciate the help.

This is my model:

```
gram <- glm(mean_animal_interaction ~ treatment+net_size+flower_family+pollinator_group, family = Gamma, data = data)
```